# qt - cannot add more than one struct onto a qlist

Tags: c++, qt, struct, qlist

**About:**

*p.s.I know this is a specific question, but I am at a loss, and have no idea why this is happening*

The algorithm below should add a struct to a list. Each struct is a `server_connection` object, and the receiving list, is contained within another struct named `VPN_Server`.

When adding the struct to the list, it holds only the very first struct added, and does not add any more.

This is confirmed by the debugger window:

for each new IP, a new `VPN_Server` struct is created and a new `server_connection` is created and `push_back`'ed onto the `ServerInstancesList` list. But when in the foreach loop, attempting to add the object is fruitless.

**Problem:**

When pushing a `server_connection` object onto a specific `VPN_Server` struct, it holds this data in the temporary foreach container, but does not apply it.

**I Have tried:**

1. adding a custom `addConnection()` method to the `VPN_Server` `struct`

   void addConnection(server_connection s_con){
       ServerInstancesList.push_back(s_con);
   }
2. Creating a temporary list, adding the server_connection and creating a new VPN_server object, and setting that equal to the current foreach container.

None of these help.

**Testing & Indepth description:**

In the algorithm, my 1st and 3rd `vpn_connection` `struct` have the same IP. On the third iteration, the foreach loop is executed and the following occurs.

`VPN_Server` ser contains info of the 1st struct info, i.e. an IP and one object in its `QList<server_connection>` called `ServerInstancesList`.

`ser` has an object added, via the `addConnection(s_con)`. Afterwards, the loop is terminated with the return. However `ser` registered the added object, while outside the foreach loop, no new object was added. Not even to any struct within the list.

It seems to be an easy fix, but I just cannot find it,

help would be appreciated!

**Code:**

**server_connection**

```
struct server_connection{

    //Is a connection contained by IP

    QString cipher,protocol;
    int port;
    bool lzo_compression;

    server_connection(){}

    server_connection(QString _cipher, QString _protocol, int _port, bool _comp){
        cipher = _cipher;
        protocol = _protocol;
        port = _port;
        lzo_compression = _comp;
    }
};
```

**VPN_Server**

```
struct VPN_Server{

    //Holds IP as sort value and list of connection info
    QString VPN_IP;
    QList<server_connection> ServerInstancesList;

    VPN_Server(){
        ServerInstancesList = QList<server_connection>();
    }

    VPN_Server(QString ip, QList<server_connection> server_con_list){
        VPN_IP = ip;
        ServerInstancesList = server_con_list;
    }

    void addConnection(server_connection s_con){
        ServerInstancesList.push_back(s_con);
    }
};
```

**Algorithm:**

```
QList<VPN_Server> data_mananger::parseVPNConnections(QList<VPNConnection> l){

    //Init var
    QList<VPN_Server> server_list = QList<VPN_Server>();
    VPNConnection v_con;
    bool bAdded = false;
    server_connection s_con;

    //processing all vpn_connections, this is raw form sent, contains as fields, ip, cipher, protocol, port, compression
    foreach (v_con, l) {

        //create server_connection - data sorted by ip
        s_con = server_connection(v_con.cipher, v_con.protocol, v_con.port, v_con.lzo_compression);

        //pass through existing data, checking for a matching ip
        foreach (VPN_Server ser, server_list) {
            if (ser.VPN_IP == v_con.ip) {
                //ip match found -> there already exists and ip with a server connection, adding another one with s_con
                ser.addConnection(s_con);
                bAdded = true;
                //break current loop short searching for a matching ip
                break;
            }
        }

        //bAdded = false -> no matching IP has been found, thus creating a nw VPNServer
        if (!bAdded) {
            VPN_Server serv;
            //creating new connection list and adding s_con to this list
            QList<server_connection> list = QList<server_connection>();
            list.push_back(s_con);

            //adding VPNServer to list containing VPNServers
            serv = VPN_Server(v_con.ip, list);
            server_list.push_back(serv);
        }
        else
            //data has been added, reseting add flag
            bAdded = false;

    }
    return server_list;
}
```

Comment: Hmm in your `foreach (VPN_Server ser, server_list)` you call `ser.addConnection(s_con);` - isn't it a call on temporary (copy) object? Looks like the loop should be changed to `foreach (VPN_Server& ser, server_list)`

Comment: @YuriyIvaskevych I tried that. Building results in error: `qglobal.h:963: error: binding ‘const Misc::VPN_Server’ to reference of type ‘Misc::VPN_Server&’ discards qualifiers
     for (variable = *_container_.i; _container_.control; _container_.control = 0)`

Comment: oops really, Qt's `foreach` indeed doesn't allow to modify (please look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600928/qt-why-is-foreach-iterating-with-a-const-reference)) . Try using simple `for`

Comment: @YuriyIvaskevych you, are a saviour. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all who helped!

Please visit the link to the QT forums below and give a thumbs up to VRonin for his solution.

Also `kudo's` to [@YuriyIvaskevych](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7095889/yuriy-ivaskevych) for helping me here on SO!

So to reiterate (budum tsss*) the [doc page](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/containers.html#the-foreach-keyword)

> Qt automatically takes a copy of the container when it enters a
>   foreach loop. If you modify the container as you are iterating, that
>   won't affect the loop. [...] using a non-const reference for the
>   variable does not allow you to modify the original container

**Solution:** created by [@VRonin from forum.qt.io](https://forum.qt.io/topic/75399/cannot-add-more-than-one-struct-onto-a-qlist-within-foreach-loop/3)

```
for (auto serIter= server_list.begin(); serIter!=server_list.end(); ++serIter) {

    if (serIter->VPN_IP == v_con.ip) {
        //ip match found -> there already exists and ip with a server connection, adding another one with s_con
        serIter->addConnection(s_con);
        bAdded = true;
        //break current loop short searching for a matching ip
        break;
    }
}
```